# Perform ESC key press over telnet connection in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, telnet

I'm trying to perform ESC key press over telnet connection in Robot Framework. Is there anyway to straight away send the key press over Telnet.Write keyword or any other alternative.

Answer (score 2):

```
${esc}=  Evaluate  chr(int(27))
Telnet.Write Bare  ${esc}
```

This worked for me

Comment: just as a side note: int() call is not really necessary but it wont cause any problems either..